# why extra word is fetch when compare two string

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am comparing two string problem is there extra word is also fetch when compare the two string.

**.cs**

```cs
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        Label1.Text = "";
        Label2.Text = "";
    }
 
     //-------------------------

    var flist = ftextbox.Text.Split(' ').Where(x => (!stextbox.Text
        .Split(' ').Contains(x))).ToList();

    int countss = flist.Count;

    foreach (var item in flist)
    {
        Label1.Text = "param1:" + string.Join("&nbsp;&nbsp;", flist);
    }

    //-------------------------
    var slist = stextbox.Text.Split(' ').Where(x => (!ftextbox.Text
        .Split(' ').Contains(x))).ToList();

    int counts = slist.Count;

    foreach (var item in slist)
    {
        Label2.Text = "param2:" + string.Join("&nbsp;&nbsp;", slist);
    }
}
```

**Current Output:**

[image: Output]

I want to remove extra word when compare two string

means **Expected Output**:

- param 1 : testing matching
- param 2 : testings matchings

help please

Answer (score 0):

Your flist didn't have "application", "by" and "website". Look at this line:

```
var slist = stextbox.Text.Split(' ').Where(x => (!ftextbox.Text.Split(' ').Contains(x))).ToList();
```

Theses words will be catch on Where method. If you just want to not compare extra words at the end of the sentences you should do something like :

```
var slist = stextbox.Text.Split(' ');
var flist = ftextbox.Text.Split(' ');
int minWordCount = Math.Min(slist.Length, flist.Length);

var diffWords = slist.Take(minWordCount).Where(x => flist.Contains(x) == false).ToList()
```